# Subscriber addresses for particular message type when using NServiceBus and RabbitMQ as transport

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus, nservicebus-rabbitmq

Is there anyway to get the list of particular message type subscriber addresses when using NServiceBus and RabbitMQ as transport ?

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus has two modes of pubsub. Native and non-native. RabbitMQ uses native pubsub. What NServiceBus does is setup the RabbitMQ routing topology based on convention.

You can use RabbitMQ management tools to see all this data.